# MySQL, select with 2+ matches from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

Have an MySQL products table like this with columns `id, tag`

Now, if I want to select products that match 2+ OR tags, I use this query:

```
SELECT id FROM products WHERE tag = 'a' OR tag = 'b' OR tag = 'c'
```

No problems there.

Problem is how to select products that match 2+ AND tags, i.e. products that matches all the specified tags. The query below to find products that have both tags `a` and `b` doesn't work:

```
SELECT id FROM products WHERE tag = 'a' AND tag = 'b'
```

Same with this attempt to find products that have at least the 3 AND tags `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
SELECT id FROM products WHERE tag = 'a' AND tag = 'b' AND tag = 'c'
```

Is there a simple way to get the products matching 2+ AND tags, just like it's simple to get the products matching OR tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select id
from products
where tag in ('a', 'b', 'c')
group by id
having count(distinct tag) = 3
```

The above query gives you all `id`s that have tags `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`.